# Setting GridPane columns/rows

Tags: java, javafx-2, fxml

Is there any way to set a GridPane amount of columns and row?

I currently have something like this:

```
<fx:root type="GridPane" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml"
         stylesheets="view/Style.css"
         maxHeight="Infinity" maxWidth="Infinity">
<gridLinesVisible>true</gridLinesVisible>
    <children>
        <Pane fx:id="center"
              GridPane.columnIndex="1" GridPane.rowIndex="1"
              GridPane.columnSpan="5" GridPane.rowSpan="3"
              GridPane.hgrow="always" GridPane.vgrow="always"/>
        <Pane fx:id="options"
              GridPane.columnIndex="0" GridPane.rowIndex="5"
              GridPane.columnSpan="6"/>
    </children>
</fx:root>
```

and I dynamically add elements into it.

The problem comes that if a row/column do not have any element it is erased, so the appearance of the pane is weird (like adding an element to (3,0) and then having elements on (2, X), (1, X) the element on (3,0) will not be centered on the pane since no element on (4,X) and (5,X))

Answer (score 0):

Use adicional HBox and VBox

```
HBox HB = new HBox();
HB.getChildren().addAll(btnexample1, btnexample2);

GridPane.setHalignment(HB, HPos.LEFT);
HB.setSpacing(5);
grid.add(HB, 0, 8);
```

Comment: ummm don't understand how to use it with my example, if i want a GridPane of 6x5 for example, how should i do it with that code? (and if possible, id preffer the use of fxml)

Comment: tried to use the [JavaFX Scene Builder 1.1](http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/javafx/downloads/devpreview-1429449.html)?

Answer (score 0):

You said it happens when there's no element. Just always have an element but make it have blank data. like Label.text = "";